# Unable to install vim in ubuntu , I am getting like this how to resolve it?

Tags: apt, software-installation, updates, update-manager, vim

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu janny-updates/matn
2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.9 404 Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80] Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu janny-updates/main
1 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.9
404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.82 80] E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/
8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.9_all.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 185.125.1
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/r e_8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.9_all.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.9 E: Fatled to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/ 95-1ubuntu2.9_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.82 8
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Your messages show *outdated* packages; eg. I looked up a package and the expected result is `vim-common | 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.10 | jammy-updates    | all` which is **not** what you're trying to get - ie. update your software lists using `sudo apt update`

Answer (score 0):

Your post was a little hard to read, but your messages show *outdated* packages;

eg. I looked up a package and the expected result is

```
vim-common | 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.10 | jammy-updates    | all
vim-common | 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.10 | jammy-security   | all
```

which is **not** what you're trying to get - ie. update your software lists using

```
sudo apt update
```

and read the output to check there are no warnings/errors that need to be dealt with; then on retry your current issue should not re-occur.